# How does rails know which precompiled asset to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

If I precompile my assets and get `application-dd7bc9cbeae7f36fe8fa239150d224d6.js` in my `public/assets` directory, change something in `application.js`, and precompile again to get `application-ff39a2b622549eaab97b2ce0a55ed0c5.js`, how does Rails know which one to use when calling `javascript_include_tag 'application'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is specified in `public/assets/manifest.yml`, which is basically a big hash table of filename => fingerprinted_filename. The manifest file is generated when you precompile your assets.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html, which says

> The rake task also generates a manifest.yml that contains a list with all your assets and their respective fingerprints. This is used by the Rails helper methods to avoid handing the mapping requests back to Sprockets.